# Android Not able to update contact details programatically in local phonebook

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, insert-update

I am having issue where i need to have update Multiple Mobile no's , Landline no's and Emails , websites , address in local phonebook contact.

If contact is already exist in phone book then i am trying to update it's details.

Below is the code i am trying. It is getting executed without error but no multiple mobile no , landline , email etc not reflecting in phone-book on that contact as the multiple data's are their.

I also referred few of the links but that didn't helped as well.

```
String whereMobile = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = ? ";

    String[] paramsMobile = new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID),
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
            String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)};


    if (userInfoMobileNos != null && !userInfoMobileNos.isEmpty()) {
        for (int iUserMobile = 0; iUserMobile < userInfoMobileNos.size(); iUserMobile++) {

            operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(whereMobile, paramsMobile)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, userInfoMobileNos.get(iUserMobile).getPhoneNumber())
                    .build());
        }

    }


String whereGmail = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE + " = ? ";

    String[] paramsGmail = new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID),
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
    String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)};

    if (userInfoGmails != null && !userInfoGmails.isEmpty()) {
    for (int iUserGmail = 0; iUserGmail < userInfoGmails.size(); iUserGmail++) {

      operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withSelection(whereGmail, paramsGmail)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, userInfoGmails.get(iUserGmail).getEmail())
                        .build());
    }

}
```

**Updated code**

```
private void updateNew(Context context, int rawContactID) {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<>();

        String whereMobile = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = ? ";

        String[] paramsMobile = new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactID),
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)};

// First delete all the existing phones with type mobile, if any exist
        operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(whereMobile, paramsMobile)
                .build());

// Next, insert all the updated phones:
        for (MobileNumbersItem infoMobileNo : userInfoMobileNos) { // <== change the class to the one you're using in userInfoMobileNos
            operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI) // <== insert not update!
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, infoMobileNo.getPhoneNumber())
                    .build());
        }

        String whereGmail = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE + " = ? ";

        String[] paramsGmail = new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactID),
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)};

        // First delete all the existing emails with type work, if any exist
        operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(whereGmail, paramsGmail)
                .build());

        // Next, insert all the updated emails:
        for (GmailsItem userInfoGmail : userInfoGmails) { // <== change the class here too
            operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, userInfoGmail.getEmail())
                    .build());
        }


        try {
            // don't forget to apply the operations now:
            ContentProviderResult[] results = context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
            Log.d("UPDATE CONTACRT", "results=" + Arrays.toString(results));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("updateContactError", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated here. I have tried to debug but can't able to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. one issue that can be either a bad parameter name, or an actual bug is that your selection is requesting a `RAW_CONTACT_ID` and supplying a parameter called `contactId`, I'm not sure what is stored in `contactId` but there's a big difference between a `rawContactId` and a `contactId`, so if that's indeed a contactId your operations will not find anything to update (or even worse, update the wrong contact).
2. The second issue is that your two loops (over `userInfoMobileNos` and `userInfoGmails`) keep updating (overriding) the same Data row, so eventually you should end up with just the last value in the contact details.
   You're also not checking if there's a Data row in the contact details that fit your selection, if there's not, there will be no row to update, and therefore the code will simply do nothing.
3. Third issue, but it may be intentional, not sure how you expect your app to work, is that you assume the info item type, i.e. you only update a phone if it's TYPE_MOBILE, and you only update the email if it's TYPE_WORK, what if there are other phones and emails stored for that contact? your code will simply keep those untouched, not sure if that intentional or not.

To fix issue one, just make sure the value in `contactId` is a **Raw**ContactId and change the name of the param.
For the second issue, you should instead do a delete-and-insert, see code below.
For the third issue, you'll need to change the selection code (`paramsMobile`) to remove it's assumption of label.

Here's suggested code:

```
String whereMobile = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
        Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
        Phone.TYPE + " = ? ";

String[] paramsMobile = new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactID),
        Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
        String.valueOf(Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)};

// First delete all the existing phones with type mobile, if any exist
operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(whereMobile, paramsMobile)
    .build());

// Next, insert all the updated phones:
for (UserInfo infoMobileNo : userInfoMobileNos) { // <== change the class to the one you're using in userInfoMobileNos
    operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI) // <== insert not update!
        operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI) // <== insert not update!
                .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, infoMobileNo.getPhoneNumber())
                .build());
}

String whereGmail = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
            Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
            Email.TYPE + " = ? ";

String[] paramsGmail = new String[]{String.valueOf(rawContactID),
Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
String.valueOf(Email.TYPE_WORK)};

// First delete all the existing emails with type work, if any exist
operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withSelection(whereGmail, paramsGmail)
    .build());

// Next, insert all the updated emails:
for (UserInfo userInfoGmail : userInfoGmails) { // <== change the class here too
    operationList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
                .withValue(Email.DATA, userInfoGmail.getEmail())
                .build());
}

// don't forget to apply the operations now:
ContentProviderResult[] results = context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
Log.d("UPDATE CONTACRT", "results=" + Arrays.toString(results));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response will look into this and get back to you.. contactId id is actually a raw contact id i am fetching it by name....

Comment: With this code it was crashing on withSelection because it is only allowed on update , delete so while insert i have tried to user code and error solved but still update contact results=[] blank. Here is the code can you look please. I have updated question with yours updated code. @marmor

Comment: good catch on the `newInsert`, i didn't test my code... i've updated the code in my answer. there is one comment, you don't need `withValueBackReference` here, this is only in case you're adding a new RawContact, which you are not.

Comment: besides the above comment, this code might sometimes not work if the raw-contact you're trying to edit is a read-only contact. If you run this (with the above fix of `withValue` instead of `withValueBackReference` on a Google raw contact, does it work?

Comment: if i remove withValueBackReference then it is giving an error System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: raw_contact_id is required so do we need to keep it or not ?

Comment: don't remove it entirely, just change it to a regular `withValue` see my updated code

Comment: Sir Thank you it's now working and storing all details in particular contact as intended thanks for your time and help !!! .... If i still stuck anywhere will get in touch with you.

Comment: Need your help on this what if i want to add fresh new contact with all multiple details if contact is not in phonebook do i need to follow same or not need to use delete at that time ? Also in that case what will be passed in rawContactId ?

Comment: Sir can you see my above comment if possible what if i need to add fresh new contact ? what should be passed in rawContactId ?

Comment: please create a new question on stackoverflow, tag it with `android-contacts`